# Migrating from .local to internet-routable domain ramifications?

Tags: active-directory, domain-name, microsoft-office-365

I've recently come to realize that having our domain end in .local is going to prevent us from being able to set up DirSync with Office 365. I plan to use Microsoft's IdFix tool to correct issues with our AD as well as migrate our domain to something like ad.example.com. I will make sure the NETBIOS and UPN to be consistent with the current domain.

Our network is two offices across the country connected by a VPN with two different subnets. We have two DCs running AD and DNS, one each location. It's a fairly small Active Directory with about 1750 directory objects.

My question is, what are the potential ramifications of this? My fear is users will be unable to log in to their PC's, services will break etc. Am I being paranoid?

Comment: So you're planning to create a new domain and migrate your existing domain to the new domain?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the best ways to go about this but that was what I had in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what services you have running (Exchange, etc), forest functional level, domain functional level, etc you may be able to use Microsoft's [Domain Rename](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738208(v=ws.10).aspx) tool which includes a good list of conditions and effects.

Regardless of the method mentioned, there is a chance users may end up unable to log into their PCs. Services and such breaking will largely depend on how well your configurations are documented, etc, as this will presumably break any references to computers/servers via the old domain name, if you have Windows DHCP servers their new names will have to be authorized or your DHCP clients won't accept their DHCP offers, etc. Keeping the same NETBIOS and UPNs (if it makes sense in your case) will help a good deal with regard to service accounts used by appliances and 3rd party software, and configurations for authorized/blocked AD groups.

I would definitely suggest (if possible) labbing the basics of your network up and going through the entire process to get a fair idea of how each step will affect the individual servers, the network as a whole, and to help fill in any holes in your implementation plan.

Answer (score 1):

For my particular scenario, I found a blog post here that sounds to be much less risky instead of a domain migration by just registering a new UPN suffix.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/How-to-prepare-a-non-routable-domain-such-as-local-domain-for-directory-synchronization-e7968303-c234-46c4-b8b0-b5c93c6d57a7